# Understanding Rust tracing info(target: "") macro and types

Tags: rust, macros

I've been enjoying navigating Rust through its type system. But when it goes into macros I find it difficult to follow. In the below example, why is it ok to pass `"target_name"` to `target` but not assign it then pass the assignment in? How do you navigate the [macro in tracing](https://docs.rs/tracing/0.1.8/src/tracing/macros.rs.html#322) such that the below is obvious to you? I am asking this as much from a developer experience perspective as a programmer. (I'm definitely looking for a "teach a man to fish" style answer.)

```
info!(target: "target_name", "message"); // fine, must be cast to &str?
let target_name = "target_name"; // must be cast to String?
info!(target: target_name, "message"); // not fine
```

The latter call results in:

```
error[E0435]: attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant
   |
44 |         info!(target: target_name, "message");
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ non-constant value
```

Even if I switch to `&target_name.as_str()` which I believe should be constant (not growable like `String`) the macro still fails with the same error. This is where my mental map is failing. I can understand that the assumed type when assigning is wrong, but then when I recast it, why would it fail?

Comment: Does it need a static lifetime? Have you tried with `const target_name : &str = "..."`?

Comment: Yes that works! So it's not just that the macro is coercing to `&str` but also that it is somehow making it `const`? Where in the macro can I read to understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to use a `const` with a type that's compatible with expectations, like:

```rust
const target_name : &str = "target_name";
```

You can usually view the source for these macros [in the documentation](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.14/log/macro.info.html), as shown here:

```rust
#[macro_export(local_inner_macros)]
macro_rules! info {
    (target: $target:expr, $($arg:tt)+) => (
        log!(target: $target, $crate::Level::Info, $($arg)+)
    );
    ($($arg:tt)+) => (
        log!($crate::Level::Info, $($arg)+)
    )
}
```

That's just a wrapper around `log!`, so it's not especially informative, and `log!` is just a wrapper around `__private_api_log` which is even less helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I've got as far as understanding using `const`, but I really want the "teach to fish" part, where I can look at the macro source and understand that `$target` needs to be `const` and how it gets coerced from what looks like String literal to me. Anything more you can say on that?

Comment: Like a lot of languages (C++ being a prime example) the source is not always that informative. The emphasis there is often on performance or correctness, not readability or any sort of understanding *at all*. I wouldn't trust the Rust internals to be very educational without a lot of supporting resources.

Comment: You can always type your variables, like `let x : Y = ...` to avoid auto-typing. I don't think a quoted string ends up as `String` automatically, I've always had to use `String::from("...")` to make it explicit.

Comment: I'll accept this as no better answer seems to exist but "just keep digging through the macros until you hit an actual type"